# Cannot solve java runtime error: ClassNotFoundException when starting java application using WebStart

Tags: java, classloader, java-web-start

I am having a terrible time trying to debug my application that is deployed to a development server. It throws the runtime error of **ClassNotFoundException** for a class in one of the dependent jar files that it needs. We use WebStart to start the application. The application update was to add security that is needed for JDK8.  All of the jars are signed and in the correct path. The JNLP file lists all of the jars needed.

I read that you can run a WebStart application using a switch **-verbose:class** that will show the class loading.  I would like to get this to run from my local machine.

When I try to use this switch, there is no additional information about class loading. The application displays the error in a GUI message box with details about the error. But I would like to see when the application is started all of the classes trying to load.

This is what I enter at the command prompt:

> C:\<>path>\javaws.exe -verbose:class -localfile
>   -J-Djnlp.application.href=http://<>path to cgi file on dev server>/tms.cgi
>   "C:\\cache\6.0\53\50d95235-2a488a0c"

If I can get the display of the jars loading from the directories, I can check it with another working version of the application and see where I am going wrong.  But I am not sure this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue of adding the verbose switch to a WebStart application.
This is what I did below in case it might help someone else...
In the JNLP file, we had a line of code like this:

```
<j2se version="1.6" max-heap-size="128m" initial-heap-size="64m"/>
```

I added this:

```
<j2se version="1.6" java-vm-args=”-verbose” max-heap-size="128m" initial-heap-size="64m"/>
```